# Console.writeline using strings

Tags: c#, string, visual-studio, console.writeline

A simple question: How do you display strings in the CMD using Console.Writeline() using C# in VS? I Know you use + for ints and floats. But what do you use for strings? This is what i have:

```
    private string productName;

    public void GetItemData()
    {
        ShowReciept();
    }

    private void ReadItem()
    {    
        Console.WriteLine("Enter the product's name: "); 
        productName = Console.ReadLine();
    }

    private void ShowReciept()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("**** Name of product:", productName);
    }
```

In void ShowReciept() it writes out everything in the Console.WriteLine command, exept the product Name. So its just blank were the product name should have been.

Comment: You couldn't Google for examples?

Comment: This is an extremely trivial issue and shows practically no research effort.

Comment: Having a trivial understanding of programming and VS, trivial issues are very recurrent for me. The examples on the forums and google did not apply 100% to my issue.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use string concatenation:

```
Console.WriteLine("**** Name of product:" + productName);
```

or you can use this:

```
Console.WriteLine("**** Name of product:{0}", productName);
```

Furthermore, if you program in C# 6, you can use string interpolation:

```
Console.WriteLine($"**** Name of product:{productName}");
```

Comment: You don't actually need to call `string.Format`. Console.WriteLine accepts format strings automatically.

Comment: Wow so +string works? I tried that and it did not work at first, so i made the conclusion that the + only worked for numbers. I tried again and it worked though thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can use a string format:

```
Console.WriteLine("**** Name of product: {0}", productName);
```